# PyMysql-Python:How to relate two inputs with a sql query?

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

Lets say for my question we have this table:

```
Actor1 Actor2 Movies
stef   bill   a
bill   stef   b
nick   nick   c
stef   stef   d
nick   bill   e
bill   nick   f
```

and we want to find the actors that played a movie and I give the name of the actors from the keyboard(input1,input2).
Obviously if the input was one actor we would have something like this:

```
sql_query='select Actor1,Actor2 from movies where Actor1= {}'.format(input1)
cursor.execute(sql_query)
```

But when i have two inputs what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two placeholders in the query. You should also let `cursor.execute()` perform the placeholder substitution, as it uses a prepared statement, rather than string formatting, which is open to SQL-injection (you also forgot the quotes around `{}`, so you would have gotten an error).

```
sql_query = 'select Actor1,Actor2 from movies where (Actor1= %s AND Actor2 = %s) OR (Actor1 = %s AND Actor2 = %s)'
cursor.execute(sql_query, (input1, input2, input2, input1))
```